# How to properly "go build" using exec.Command with many arguments?

Tags: go, command-line

I'm trying to compile a go package using exec.Command. I was successful with the arguments being "go" and "build" as such below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("go", "build").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

However, while trying to perform a "go build" with more arguments it seems that I'm doing something wrong? This is what my code looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("set", "GOOS=js&&", "set", "GOARCH=wasm&&", "go", "build", "-o", "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/go-workspace/src/sandbox/other/wasm/assets/json.wasm", "kard").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

The output is `exec: "set": executable file not found in %PATH%`

The normal command I would perform for this in the command line would be `set GOOS=js&& set GOARCH=wasm&& go build -o C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\go-workspace\src\sandbox\other\wasm\assets\json.wasm kard`.

I assume there is something I'm misunderstanding with using exec.Command? I really appreciate any support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application uses shell syntax to set the environment variables, but the exec package does not use a shell (unless the command that you are running is a shell).

Use the [command environment](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Env) to specify the environment variables for the exec'ed command.

The `go build` does not normally write to stdout, but it does write errors to stderr.  Use CombinedOutput instead of Output to easily capture error text.

```
cmd := exec.Command("go", "build", "-o", "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/go-workspace/src/sandbox/other/wasm/assets/json.wasm", "kard")
cmd.Env = []string{"GOOS=js", "GOARCH=wasm"}
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%v: %s\n", err, out)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this seems to not properly function either for some reason. It errors out and outputs: `exit status 1` (from the response to the cmd) and nothing is compiled.

Comment: @Gradesh Find out what the `go` command is complaining about using the information in the updated answer.

Comment: Yup that did it! Was able to debug the error and is working now :). Love you <3